How to Troubleshoot Problem with CUDA not seeing GPU ./deviceQuery return cudaGetDeviceCount 802 System not yet Initialized
I’m new to CUDA and GPU stuff. I have an older GPU a GT 720. My goal is to get tortoise-tts working. I guess, I’m assuming I need CUDA to do this.
On bare metal, I installed Ubuntu 20.04 and the proprietary Nvidia (nvidia-driver-470).
Based on this I came up with these versions of cuda and cuda-drivers.
sudo apt-get install cuda=11.4.4-1 cuda-drivers=470.239.06-1

Everything installs correctly, but when I try to run the cuda-samples (11.4 version), they don’t work.
If I run the deviceQuery one, I get this.
./deviceQuery Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

cudaGetDeviceCount returned 802
-> system not yet initialized
Result = FAIL

All of the cuda 11.4 samples fail the same way. I assume this means Cuda can’t see my Nvidia device. So my questions are:
Do I need to even do this?
If so, how do I troubleshoot this issue?
Should I use the proprietary Nvidia driver or are there better options?


Please ask here instead: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/gpu-graphics/linux/148
